# writing a package.json command with a dynamically changing variable

Tags: bash, shell, package.json

I am trying to write a custom script inside of a `package.json` that runs a migration. The command needs the path to the file you want to run so I need that to be a dynamic variable. Below that would be the variable `${path}`

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "migrate": "contentful space migration -s %NEXT_PUBLIC_CONTENTFUL_SPACE% ${path}"
  },
```

then I can run `npm run migrate some_folder/test`

is this achievable?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should achieve what you wanted :

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "migrate": "bash -c 'contentful space migration -s %NEXT_PUBLIC_CONTENTFUL_SPACE% $@' bash"
  },
```

Now `npm run migrate some_folder/test` should work.